# How to change the column names in gt?

Tags: r, gt

How can I add bracklets () in column names using the gt package in R?
column name in r = `grp35_rs12468485`. What I want: `grp35(rs12468485)`

I already created a table with the gt package:

```
table1_pgx <- pgx_rs %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("pgx")
  )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be find on: https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html

For me this worked:

```
pgx_table <- pgx_rs %>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("pgx")
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    grp35_rs12468485 = html("gpr35(rs12468485)")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for such a solution: Here in the iris example dataset the string after `.` is enclosed in parenthesis in all column names. In your case you could replace `.` by `_`

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename_with(~str_c(str_replace(., "\\.", "("), ")")) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]